# Is the 11th dimension in M-theory a line or a circle?

Tags: string-theory, supergravity

I'm familiarizing myself with $M$-theory and I think I get the big picture now, but I've read different accounts on this. According to some expositions by people that I think know what they are talking about, the 11th dimension in $M$-theory is a line and we live in one of the 10-dimensional fibers over the boundaries of that line, but in other accounts I've read the 11th dimension is wrapped up in a circle. I understand $M$-theory can be developed on different spacetimes, but both accounts claim to explain the current model of the universe, (so I'm assuming they mean G2-MSSM). So which one is it?

Comment: The 10-dimensional boundary of a line? Huh?

Comment: @Oбжорoв What I mean is that the fiber  of the projection of the manifold onto the 11th dimension is 10-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

if any of the additional dimensions hypothesised in the various version of string theory (including M-theory) were infinite (in simple terms, a "line") then we would notice them in everyday life. Therefore all such additional dimensions must be [compactified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics)) or wrapped around at a very small scale. You can describe each individual dimension as a circle, but what is important is how they combine with one another topologically

Comment: In "heterotic M-theory", the 11th dimension is a line interval between two boundaries called "end-of-the-world branes". At weak coupling, the line interval becomes short and the theory reduces to 10d E8xE8 heterotic string.